# Dynamic templating based on list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, templates, object, dynamic

What is the best way to automatically generate templates in following scenario.

Group of objects:

```
Article
  |- Id
  |- Text
Gallery
  |- Id
  |- Type
  |- List<Photos>
Video
  |- Id
  |- VideoHash
```

All these objects are located in `var list = new List<dynamic>()`. So page which consists of:

```
1. article
2. gallery
3. article
4. video
```

Would have object like this:

```
list.Add(Article)
list.Add(Gallery)
list.Add(Article)
list.Add(Video)
```

Now my question, what is the best way to create templates for particular object and then when generating page to call particular template, bind it with object data and send to browser as .ToString().

Is it possible to do withing .net or do I have to use some templating library?

**UPDATE**

To clarify question, I am asking what is the best technology, library, component to generate HTML code for website from dynamic list.

Idea is that I create HTML template for article, for video, for gallery and then I run page and it will generate whole page with templates generated from this dynamic list.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Can you create a set of classes for each object you want in the list?

Comment: I think I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to create a webpage-__skeleton__ from C#-list objects, or do you want to create actual webpages from C#-lists?

Comment: I want to create HTML code from c# list. HTML should be generated using templates (user controls, T4 library) where I define how template for article should look, for video, for gallery. Then it should be all joined and returned as HTML. Sorry for confusion, maybe I should rewrite whole q.

Comment: @feronovak why not use MVC, which has the Razor templating engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamics are not type safe and do not provide intellisense. You should avoid them in most scenarios. Create a class hierarchy instead

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Article : Item
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Gallery : Item
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}

public class Video : Item
{
    public string VideoHash { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can create a list of items

```
var list = new List<Item>();
lst.Add(new Article { Id = 1, Text = "test" });
lst.Add(new Video { Id = 1, VideoHash = "34Rgw^2426@62#$%" });
```

A class serves as template for objects. Derived classes inherit the members from the base class (here `Id`).

---

**UPDATE**

A T4 template migth look like this

```
<#@ template inherits="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.ModelingTextTransformation" language="C#v3.5" debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".html" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly name="mscorlib.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly name="C:\Users\Oli\Documents\Proj\CySoft\StackOverflowTests\StackOverflowTests\bin\Debug\StackOverflowTests.exe" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="StackOverflowTests.CreateHtmlFromClasses" #>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <table style="Width:100%;">
        <# this.AddProperties(new Article { Id = 77, Text = "The quick brown fox." }); #>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<#+
    private void AddProperties(object obj)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();#>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b><#= type.Name #></b>
            </td>
        </tr>
<#+         foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties) {
#>      <tr>
            <td>
                <#= property.Name #>
            </td>
            <td>
                <#= property.GetValue(obj, null).ToString() #>
            </td>
        </tr>
<#+
        }   
    }
#>
```

This example is not a real world example, since it uses the values of an object that of cause would only exist at runtime. You would do only operations based on types. The template engine cannot access types of the current project. Therefore you would have to place it in another project.

Comment: Thanks for tips, still how do you template list like that? I mean, what you use for templating? user controls? T4 library? To get all these classes as HTML for browser.

Comment: Yeah you can use T4. T4 looks a bit messy because HTML and C# code are mixed together, but it does its job.